# Ruby throws Date::Error on a valid date (DateTime.parse)

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

I'm using Ruby's `date` module to convert/parse my date into a DateTime object. To do this, I'm using `DateTime.parse(<time>)`. But it throws `Date::Error` even though it's a valid date. Full error message:

```
2022-07-13 09:54:48 - Date::Error - invalid date:
        main.rb:123:in `parse'
        main.rb:123:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        main.rb:121:in `each'
        main.rb:121:in `block in <main>'
```

Code that throws the error:

```rb
time = DateTime.parse(client["properties"]["closedate"])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would be possible to add in your question what is the return of client["properties"]["closedate"], please?